# Postgres and Spring Data JPA: operator does not exist: bytea = bigint

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a N-N Product-Category model, and I've made a Spring Data JPA @Query to retrieve products of a given category (or all products if category is null):

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT obj FROM Product obj INNER JOIN obj.categories cats WHERE "
    + "(:category IS NULL OR :category IN cats)")
Page<Product> find(Category category, Pageable pageable);
```

It works perfectly in H2 database. However, when testing in Postgres 12, if a null category is given, I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bytea = bigint
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Coalesce saved me once in the past for similar issue with a parameter of type Instant, but this time it did NOT solve the problem for an entity parameter:

```
    + "(COALESCE(:category, NULL) IS NULL OR :category IN cats)")
```

Just in case, I've tested only for NULL and it doesn't throw any errors for both null and not null categories:

```
    + "(:category IS NULL")
```

I've also tested only the IN clause, and got the same "operator does not exist" error when a null category is given:

```
    + "(:category IN cats)")
```

Tests have shown that, apparently, the `:category IS NULL` condition before OR operator is not preventing the `:category IN cats` of being evaluated. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hey Nelio, did you find any solution for that? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

After facing the same problem as you and tried several different solutions I found one that works fine with postgreSQL.

Instead passing the list as null you can pass the list as a emptyList()

So I add a Ternary at my code to validate if the parameter is null if so I pass a `Collections.emptyList();`

Hope this help you too :)

Comment: You're a life savior!! Simple and ellegant. Thanks man